# Как закрыть консольную программу внутри этой программы? C#

Tags: c#, консоль

Есть программа, в которой вводятся некие данные. Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе неверных данных программа закрывалась?

Comment: А что мешает везде сделать return - и программа завершится.

Comment: Что мешает проверить жив ли процесс по открытому дескриптору из "внутри этой программы" и тоже завершится.

Answer (score 0):

Для завершения процесса используйте [Environment.Exit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score -3):

Нужно выдать исключение, вроде:

```
throw new Exception("Пипец всему!");
```

Либо просто

```
void Main(){
     //твой код
     if (error) return;
}
```

Comment: За что минус то? Ответ по теме, все работает.

Comment: При чем тут исключение? Оно совсем не закрывает программу.

Comment: Ой блин, совсем забыл

Comment: Он просто останавливает выполнение программы, разве не это нужно?

Comment: При неверных данных вроде так принято делать

Comment: Выкинутое исключение принято ловить и обрабатывать. А при обработке возникает та же самая проблема - как завершить работу программы. Поэтому я и говорю - исключение тут совсем ни при чем, программу закрывают не исключением.